# Can someone help me with a small JavaScript setTimeout problem?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to cut down the numbers of the event execution time
and so I wrote something like this:

```
var slow=function(method,context){
    method.id&&clearTimeout(method.id)
    method.id = setTimeout(function(){
        method.apply(context,arguments)
    }, 500)
}

window.onload=function(){
    function print(){ console.log("thanks a lot") }
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){
        slow(print)
    }, false)
}
```

If I move too fast in the body, and the `print` function won't be executed immediately, but it doesn't seem to be work.
Can somebody help?

Comment: What does the print function do?  JavaScript is single threaded - if print takes a while, it will be a while before the next one (for the subsequent mouse moves) fires

Answer (score 0):

At first look, You have'nt provided the context parameter in the call to slow

Comment: parameters are optional in JavaScript.  If it's not specified, it is simply 'undefined', and using  method.apply(context,arguments) with context as undefined just means the context will be the 'window' object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Ben Alman's throttle/debounce plugin. It doesn't actually require jQuery at all. If you don't have jQuery on the page, it just adds itself to the `Cowboy` namespace.

https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/blob/master/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js

Otherwise, you could at least get a good idea of how he does this from the code here.